# Next JS Image Optimization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

How can I use the NextJS `Image` element in raw HTML response from the server something like:

```html
HTML =
"<div>
<p> Some Random text</p>
<img src="image1.jpg" />
<img src="image2.jpg" />
<p> Some Random text</p>
<img src="image3.jpg" />
<img src="image4.jpg" />
<div>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Next.js `Image` element is React component so it can only be used in React (with Next.js).

```
export default function Page() {
   return (
      <Image src="/image.png" layout="fill" />
   )
}
```

If you want image optimization with just raw HTML, I would recommend installing [ImgBot](https://imgbot.net/) in a GitHub repository, and it will optimize the images for you and save them in the file.